# SQL joining large table performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-indexes

There is a relational database structure that has a number of Machines. On each day a Machine will have a MachineActivity for that day. A MachineActivity will have up to 24 HourHistory's against it each day, the HourHistory logs some minutes against an hour period of up to 60 minutes, there are constraints on the HourHistory table to ensure that the 24 in Hour and 60 in Minutes are upheld. Therefore the table structure looks something like this.

```
MACHINE
Id
MachineNumber

MACHINEACTIVITY
Id
MachineId
ActivityDate

HOURHISTORY
Id
MachineActivityId
Hour (0-23)
Minutes (0-60)
```

I am using a stored procedure to try and bring back a row for each MachineActivity and sort the hours into columns and bring back the minutes in those columns, so looking at a 24 hour period and seeing the minutes in each of the hour columns, e.g.

**MachineActivity.Id | HourHistory.Hour1Minutes | HourHistory.Hour2Minutes etc**

I have tried two methods for doing this in the stored procedure, first joining once on the HourHistory table and using a bunch of CASE statements to bring out the corresponding HourMinutes, this is the slowest in performance:

```
SELECT 
    MA.ActivityDate,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 0 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes00,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 1 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes01,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 2 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes02,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 3 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes03,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 4 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes04,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 5 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes05,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 6 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes06,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 7 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes07,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 8 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes08,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 9 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes09,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 10 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes10,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 11 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes11,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 12 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes12,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 13 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes13,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 14 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes14,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 15 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes15,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 16 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes16,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 17 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes17,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 18 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes18,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 19 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes19,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 20 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes20,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 21 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes21,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 22 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes22,
    (CASE WHEN EHH."Hour" = 23 THEN EHH.EngineMinutes ELSE 0 END) AS HourMinutes23
FROM
    MachineActivity MA
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH ON EHH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
```

The second method, which surprisingly gives a better result performance-wise joins a new HourHistory for each of the Hour slots in a day:

```
SELECT 
    MA.ActivityDate,
    ISNULL((EHH.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes00,
    ISNULL((EHH1.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes01,
    ISNULL((EHH2.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes02,
    ISNULL((EHH3.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes03,
    ISNULL((EHH4.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes04,
    ISNULL((EHH5.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes05,
    ISNULL((EHH6.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes06,
    ISNULL((EHH7.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes07,
    ISNULL((EHH8.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes08,
    ISNULL((EHH9.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes09,
    ISNULL((EHH10.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes10,
    ISNULL((EHH11.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes11,
    ISNULL((EHH12.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes12,
    ISNULL((EHH13.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes13,
    ISNULL((EHH14.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes14,
    ISNULL((EHH15.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes15,
    ISNULL((EHH16.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes16,
    ISNULL((EHH17.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes17,
    ISNULL((EHH18.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes18,
    ISNULL((EHH19.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes19,
    ISNULL((EHH20.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes20,
    ISNULL((EHH21.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes21,
    ISNULL((EHH22.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes22,
    ISNULL((EHH23.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes23   
FROM
    MachineActivity MA
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH ON EHH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH."Hour" = 0
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH1 ON EHH1.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH1."Hour" = 1
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH2 ON EHH2.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH2."Hour" = 2
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH3 ON EHH3.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH3."Hour" = 3
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH4 ON EHH4.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH4."Hour" = 4
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH5 ON EHH5.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH5."Hour" = 5
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH6 ON EHH6.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH6."Hour" = 6
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH7 ON EHH7.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH7."Hour" = 7
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH8 ON EHH8.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH8."Hour" = 8
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH9 ON EHH9.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH9."Hour" = 9
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH10 ON EHH10.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH10."Hour" = 10
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH11 ON EHH11.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH11."Hour" = 11
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH12 ON EHH12.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH12."Hour" = 12
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH13 ON EHH13.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH13."Hour" = 13
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH14 ON EHH14.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH14."Hour" = 14
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH15 ON EHH15.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH15."Hour" = 15
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH16 ON EHH16.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH16."Hour" = 16
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH17 ON EHH17.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH17."Hour" = 17
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH18 ON EHH18.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH18."Hour" = 18
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH19 ON EHH19.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH19."Hour" = 19
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH20 ON EHH20.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH20."Hour" = 20
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH21 ON EHH21.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH21."Hour" = 21
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH22 ON EHH22.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH22."Hour" = 22
LEFT JOIN
    HourHistory EHH23 ON EHH23.MachineActivityId = MA.Id AND EHH23."Hour" = 23
```

There are a huge number of records in the HourHistory table, both statements are will be restricted to a maximum of a month periods. I have tried putting indexes on the HourHistory table in various combinations but they seem to actually slow it down instead of the desired speeding up effect.

This is a big issue for me, these are taking up to 10 seconds to bring back data which just isn't quick enough for the end-users. Any feedback on how I could increase the performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two queries produce different result sets.

Comment: I'm not receiving different results, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to filter your tables first before applying any `joins`.

```
SELECT 
    MA.ActivityDate,
    ISNULL((EHH.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes00,
    ISNULL((EHH1.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes01,
    ISNULL((EHH2.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes02,
    ISNULL((EHH3.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes03,
    ISNULL((EHH4.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes04,
    ISNULL((EHH5.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes05,
    ISNULL((EHH6.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes06,
    ISNULL((EHH7.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes07,
    ISNULL((EHH8.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes08,
    ISNULL((EHH9.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes09,
    ISNULL((EHH10.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes10,
    ISNULL((EHH11.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes11,
    ISNULL((EHH12.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes12,
    ISNULL((EHH13.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes13,
    ISNULL((EHH14.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes14,
    ISNULL((EHH15.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes15,
    ISNULL((EHH16.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes16,
    ISNULL((EHH17.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes17,
    ISNULL((EHH18.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes18,
    ISNULL((EHH19.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes19,
    ISNULL((EHH20.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes20,
    ISNULL((EHH21.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes21,
    ISNULL((EHH22.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes22,
    ISNULL((EHH23.EngineMinutes), 0) AS HourMinutes23   
FROM
    MachineActivity MA
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 0) EHH ON EHH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 1) EHH1 ON EHH1.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 2) EHH2 ON EHH2.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 3) EHH3 ON EHH3.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 4) EHH4 ON EHH4.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 5) EHH5 ON EHH5.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 6) EHH6 ON EHH6.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 7) EHH7 ON EHH7.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 8) EHH8 ON EHH8.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 9) EHH9 ON EHH9.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 10) EHH10 ON EHH10.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 11) EHH11 ON EHH11.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 12) EHH12 ON EHH12.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 13) EHH13 ON EHH13.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 14) EHH14 ON EHH14.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 15) EHH15 ON EHH15.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 16) EHH16 ON EHH16.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 17) EHH17 ON EHH17.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 18) EHH18 ON EHH18.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 19) EHH19 ON EHH19.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 20) EHH20 ON EHH20.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 21) EHH21 ON EHH21.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 22) EHH22 ON EHH22.MachineActivityId = MA.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    (select EngineMinutes from HourHistory where "Hour" = 23) EHH23 ON EHH23.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
```

Comment: Thanks but not a noticeable improvement I'm afraid.